# Using static properties with typescript, node, and babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs

I am trying to create a static class property

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

class Test {
  static name = 'abc';
}
```

which gets transpilled by typescript to

```
require("babel-polyfill");

class Test {
}
Test.name = 'abc';
```

Now when I run this using babel-node, I get

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function Test()
```

My babelrc looks like this:

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties", "syntax-class-properties"]
}
```

Any idea what could be the error? Should the transpilled code look different (i.e. a problem with my typescript config) or am I missing yet another babel plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the name that you chose for that static property. It conflicts with the property `name` of functions (which constructors and classes are) which is readonly.

[Spec for property `name` of Function instances](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-name)

Technically, `name` can still be replaced because the property is `configurable`, so it can be replaced with `Object.defineOwnProperty`. It's just the way `transform-class-properties` assigns the static properties to the constructor. It needs to use `Object.defineOwnProperty` and not just do the assignment like that.

Honestly, it'd be best if you avoid `name`, `length` and `prototype` as static class properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MinusFour!